# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un aviso que dice warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast. En mi código?

Tags: c

En este programa de arreglo bidimensional debe tener dos opciones una que primero primero permita ingresar los datos de los productos caducados y la segunda opción que imprima esos datos entonces ya tengo mas o menos hecho el código pero el problema que me salen varios errores como es el siguiente: **warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]** y no funciona correctamente , si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería muchísimo por que no se muy bien como se lo resuelve y llevo rato intentando

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define tam 100
#define iva 0.12
void ProductosAgotados(int[][tam],char[][tam],int[][tam],float[][tam]);
void ImpresionDatos(int[][tam],char[][tam],int[][tam],float[][tam]);
float ValorTotal(int[][tam],int[][tam],float[][tam]);

void main() 
{
    int op,cantProdAgotados[tam][tam],cant[tam][tam],cantProd [tam][tam];
    float precio[tam][tam];
    char nombreProducto[tam][tam];
     while(op!=3)
    {
        printf("\n1.Productos Agotados(Ingreso de datos)\n2.Impresion de Datos\n3.Salir\n");
        printf("Escoja la opción:");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                   printf("Usted ha ingresado a la opción 1\n");
                   
                   ProductosAgotados(cantProdAgotados,nombreProducto,cant,precio);
                   getchar();
                   getchar();
                   system("clear");
                   
            break;
            case 2:
                  ImpresionDatos(cantProdAgotados,nombreProducto,cant,precio);
                  getchar();
                  getchar();
                  system("clear");
            break;
            case 3:
                  
                   printf("Fin del programa\n");
            break;
            default:
                    printf("Opción inválida.Intente nuevamente\n");
            break;
        }
    }    
}

void ProductosAgotados(int cantProdAgotados[][tam],char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[][tam],float precio[][tam])
{
    int i,j,cont1=1, cont=0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantProdAgotados[i][j]; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cant[i][j]; ++j)
        {   
            
                 while(i<=cantProdAgotados[i][j])
                    {
                        
                        while(cont1<=cantProdAgotados[i][j])
                        {
                            getchar();
                            printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto:");
                            fgets(nombreProducto[i][j],tam,stdin);
                            while(cant[i][j]<0);
                            {
                               printf("Ingrese la cantidad:");
                               scanf("%d",&cant[i][j]); 
                            }
                            while(precio[i][j]<0); 
                            {
                                 printf("Ingrese el precio:");
                               scanf("%f",&precio[i][j]);
                            
                            }
                        }
                      }
        }
    }
}

void ImpresionDatos(int cantProdAgotados[][tam],char nombreProducto[][tam],int cant[][tam],float precio[][tam])
{
      int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<cantProdAgotados[i][j];i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<cant[i][j];j++)
        {
          printf("Datos de la lista N°%d\n",i+1);
          printf("Cantidad de productos:%d\n",cant[i][j]);
          printf("Nombre del producto%s\n",nombreProducto[i][j]);//
          printf("Precio:%.1f\n",precio[i][j]);
        }
        
    }
    printf("El total es:%.2f\n", ValorTotal(cantProdAgotados,cant,precio));
}

float ValorTotal(int cantProdAgotados[][tam],int cant[][tam],float precio[][tam])
{
    int i,j;
    float valorUnitario=0,subtotal=0,iva1=0,total=0;
    for(i=0;i<cantProdAgotados[i][j];i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<cant[i][j];j++)
        {
             valorUnitario=(cant[i][j])*(precio[i][j]);
             subtotal=subtotal+valorUnitario;
             iva1=subtotal*iva;
             total=subtotal+iva1;
        }
        
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir que el programa no ejecuta bien? aclara eso...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la recomendación , lo tomaré muy en cuenta para futuras ocasiones y ya reformularé bien esta pregunta

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a cómo implementar la función `fgets`. Aquí tienes la declaración y la implementación, con un ejemplo incluido https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm

Answer (score 3):

La función [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) de `<stdio.h>` tiene la siguiente firma:

```
char *fgets( char *restrict str, int count, FILE *restrict stream );
```

El primer parámetro es un puntero a caracter. Tú estás llamando a la función así:

```
fgets(nombreProducto[i][j],tam,stdin);
```

La variable `nombreProducto` está definida como:

```
#define tam 100

...
...

char nombreProducto[tam][tam];
```

Es decir, como primer parámetro le estás pasando un `char` no un puntero. O te falta una dimensión:

```
char nombreProducto[tam][tam][tam];
```

O te sobra una des-referencia:

```
fgets(nombreProducto[i],tam,stdin);
//                  ^^^ <--- Sólo una des-referencia.
```